# Predicate calculus validity.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is this predicate calculus statement , valid?

∃x,(P(x)∨Q(x))⇒(~∀x,P(x))∨∃x,Q(x)

Please explain the proof in detail.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** valid : to show it, it is enough to produce a counterexample.

Consider a "universe" with only one white ball.

Consider the following interpretation for the predicate letters $P$ and $Q$ :

> $P(x)$ is interpreted as "$x$ is white" and $Q(x)$ is interpreted as "$x$ is black".

According to this interpetation, $\exists x (P(x)\lor Q(a))$ is *true* : in our interpretation it is true that "there is a ball $b$ such that : either $b$ is white or $b$ is black".

But $\exists x Q(x)$ is *false* : there are no balck balls, and also $\lnot \forall x P(x)$ is *false*, because we have only one white ball, and thus it is *true* that "all balls are white".

Thus, the *disjunction* : $\lnot \forall x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)$ is *false*, because both its disjuncts are.

*Conclusion* : in the said interpretation the antecedent of the conditional is *true* while the consequent is *false*, and thus the conditional is *false*.

Having found an interpretation where the conditional is false it is enough to conclude that it is **not** *valid* (because *valid* means : "true in **all** interpretations").

Answer (score 0):

It's false. Let $P$ be "$\top$" (or any tautology) and $Q$ "$\bot$". The left-hand side is true - let $x=\emptyset$, for instance. The right-hand side is false: it is not true that "not forall $x$, $\top$" - that is, it's true that for all $x$, $\top$ - and there does not exist $x$ such that $\bot$.